# How to get a tkinter askdirectory window with an address bar on top?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

I am using `filedialog.askdirectory()` to choose a directory but it opens a window like this:
[image: This does not have an address bar on top]

But I intend to open a window like this:
[image: This has an address bar on top]

Is it possible to get a window with an address bar using `askdirectory()` or is there any other way to do it in tkinter?

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do this in tkinter. Tkinter uses native dialogs, and it provides no way to customize them.